# Content property doesn't inherit css classes

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, I need to add a `logo` to the `image`. The `logo` should show up only on `hover`. Currently, I have this class that is reacting by darkening on hovering:

```
.et_pb_video_overlay_hover {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

But when I add there `content:url(...)` it will show up in the class straight away.
I tried to do

```
.et_pb_video_overlay :hover{
    content: url(https://www.aatevr.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/te-Aate-VR-healthcare-Virtual-Reality-e1574673050893.png);

}
```

But then it doesn't inherit the fading in and out beside the size is all over the image and I would need it to be smaller and in the center.
Is there any way, that I can move just around the content property to make it easy in and out and scale it down without messing up the previous property?

Comment: The `content` property is not animatable.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1):

You can move it on :before

like this:

```
.content:hover:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(https://www.aatevr.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/te-Aate-VR-healthcare-Virtual-Reality-e1574673050893.png);
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Enjoy!

https://codesandbox.io/s/hover-logo-image-show-jtrh4

Answer (score 0):

Set `content` empty by default in this class `.et_pb_video_overlay`

```
.et_pb_video_overlay{
  content: '';
}
```

and then on hover

```
.et_pb_video_overlay:hover{
    content: url(https://www.aatevr.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/te-Aate-VR-healthcare-Virtual-Reality-e1574673050893.png);

}
```

It will work and also you both classes are different `.et_pb_video_overlay`and `.et_pb_video_overlay_hover`

Comment: I tried that and I am aware that both of my classes are different, that is why I don't understand that it doesn't work. I tried your solution, but it doesn't inherit the transition or the scale. When I add it to the overlay_hover class, it shows without hovering, which I dont understand since the rest of it shows only on hovering

Comment: Can you provide us a minimal html and css working example of your code